# Flask stores and count the number of view

Tags: database, flask

I'm making a flask blog, I add a new feature InIt, and It can help to count how many views does current post has, but is there any way that I can present with html code instead of return. Because If I want to get the number of viewer, I won't see the post, but If I want to see the post, I won't see the number, so i want to see the number of view for different post, how should I fix the problem?

routes.py

```
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
@login_required
def post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id) # post = Get post by post_id
    return render_template('post.html', title=post.title, post=post)

@app.route("/visit")
@login_required 
def visit():
    v = Visit.query.first()
    if not v:
        v = Visit()
        v.count += 1
        db.session.add(v)
    v.count +=1
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(counter=v.count)
```

post.html

```
<html>
<!-- <p>{{ visit.count }}</p> -->
<article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + post.author.image_file) }}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{{ url_for('user_posts', username=post.author.username) }}">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
        <br>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') }}</small>
        {% if post.author == current_user %}
          <div>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('update_post', post_id=post.id) }}">Update</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="post-title">
        <h2 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
      </div>
      <article>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              {{ post.content }}
            </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <br>
      <div class="post-tag">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">{{ post.tag }}</button>
      </div>
      <br>
          <hr>
                <br>
            
          <div>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('allcomment', post_id=post.id ) }}"><i class='far fa-comment-alt'></i>See all comments</a>

                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('commentpost', post_id=post.id ) }}"><i class='far fa-comment-alt'></i>Write comments</a>
            </div>
              </div>
  </article>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
```

This line looks suspicious, shouldn't the return be inside the if ?

Comment: How did you fix it in the end? I'm curious :)